# MS SQL Server STIntersects OR STIntersects is too slow

Tags: sql-server, geography, spatial-query

I am querying a table with a geography column that is a LINESTRING. My query is basically this:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable 
WHERE geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((...coords for poly A...)),4326).STIntersects(geo) = 1 
OR geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((...coords for poly B...)),4326).STIntersects(geo) = 1
```

This query results in 81 records and takes 16 seconds.

If I break it into 2 separate querys:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable 
WHERE geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((...coords for poly A...)),4326).STIntersects(geo) = 1 

SELECT id FROM mytable 
WHERE geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((...coords for poly B...)),4326).STIntersects(geo) = 1
```

They return 51 and 31 records (1 in common) respectively and take virtually no time to execute.

Why is the OR so unusably slow?  Do I have to resort to multiple queries and post processing to implement something so basic or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In this exact case, you can get what you're looking for by unjoining the two queries together. Alternatively, you can preprocess your polygons into one geography instance with STUnion.

Comment: I agree with Ben, I would be interested to know how the query performs using a MULTIPOLYGON (the result of an STUnion) rather than 2 polygons.

Also, have you compared the 2 query plans?

Comment: Using STUnion() does resolve the issue.  I have not compared the 2 query plans, I am not sure how to do that - pointers would be appreciated.  I find it odd that MS SQL Server can't do an OR when the same query runs instantly in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Hilo in SQL Server Management studio there is a button for viewing query plans.  To the right of execute you have the buttons Debug, stop, parse, **Display Estimated Query Plan**, Query Options, Intellisense Enabled, **Include Actual Execution Plan**.  Those two buttons will give you the actual actions SQL Server will be taking to perform your query.  It sounds like your spatial index may be be being used properly, but without the query plans I am not certain.